# Division of two vectors? State-space model to transfer function

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, control-theory

The transfer function is $G(s)=Y(s)/U(s)$, where $U(s)$ is the input function and $Y(s)$ is the output function.

**But how is this fraction justified if $Y(s)$ and $U(s)$ are vectors/matrices?**

[I have the following derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation#Transfer_function) of the transfer function from a state-space model. But I don't understand equation $(6)$ below.

> \begin{align}
> \dot{\mathbf x}(t)&=A\mathbf x(t)+ B\mathbf u(t)\tag{1}\\
> \mathbf y(t)&=C\mathbf x(t)+ D\mathbf u(t)\tag{2}
> \end{align}
>   where $\mathbf x(t)\in \mathbb R^n$, $\mathbf y(t)\in \mathbb R^q, \mathbf u(t)\in\mathbb R^p$. The matrices are $A^{n\times n}$, $B^{n\times p}$, $C^{q\times n}$ and $D^{q\times p}$.
>
> The Laplace transform of $(1)$, where the initial value is zero, gives
>   $$
> s\mathbf X(s)=A\mathbf X(s)+ B \mathbf U(s)\tag{3}
> $$
>
> Simplifying this gives $(s\mathbf I-A)\mathbf X(s)=B\mathbf U(s)$, so
>   $$
> \mathbf X(s)=(s\mathbf I-A)^{-1}B\mathbf U(s) \tag{4}
> $$
>
> Now, the Laplace transform of $(2)$ is 
>   $$
> \mathbf Y(s)=C\mathbf X(s)+D\mathbf U(s) \tag{5}
> $$
>   Substituting $(4)$ in $(5)$ yields
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbf Y(s)&=C(s\mathbf I-A)^{-1}B\mathbf U(s)+ D\mathbf U(s)\\
> &=(C(s\mathbf I-A)^{-1}B+ D)\mathbf U(s)
> \tag{6}
> \end{align}
>   Therefore the transfer function is
>   $$
> \mathbf G(s)=C(s\mathbf I-A)^{-1}B+D \tag{7}
> $$

How can we divide the vectors $\mathbf Y(s)$ and $\mathbf U(s)$ in $(6)$ to form the transfer function $\mathbf G(s)=\frac{\mathbf Y(s)}{\mathbf U(s)}$ in $(7)$?

Answer (score 1):

There is no division here. We know that 
$$
\mathbf Y(s)=M(s)\mathbf U(s)
=(C(s\mathbf I-A)^{-1}B+ D)\mathbf U(s)
$$

where $M(s)$ is the transfer funcion ( a matrix in this case).

Comment: Hmm, but I have to solve for $\mathbf M(s)$? If $\mathbf Y(s)=\mathbf M(s) \mathbf U(s)$ "division" with $\mathbf U(s)$ gives $\mathbf M(s)=\frac{\mathbf Y(s)}{\mathbf U(s)}$. How do you mean?

Comment: @JDoeDoe You can't really define [such fraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111652/can-we-divide-two-vectors) in general. The transfer function $G(s)$ is just defined that if you multiply it by $U(s)$ you get $Y(s)$.